# Python "list index out of range" error

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

My goals is to have a list of lists, where each item in the outer list contains a word in it's first index, and the number of times it has come across it in the second index. As an example, it should look like this:

```
[["test1",0],["test2",4],["test3",8]]
```

The only issue is that when I try to, for instance, access the word "test1" from the first inner-list, I get an index out of range error. Here is my code for how I am attempting to do this:

```
stemmedList = [[]]

f = open(a_document_name, 'r')

#read each line of file
fileLines = f.readlines()
for fileLine in fileLines:
    #here we end up with stopList, a list of words
    thisReview = Hw1.read_line(fileLine)['text']
    tokenList = Hw1.tokenize(thisReview)
    stopList = Hw1.stopword(tokenList)

    #for each word in stoplist, compare to all terms in return list to
    #see if it exists, if it does add one to its second parameter, else
    #add it to the list as ["word", 0]
    for word in stopList:
        #if list not empty
        if not len(unStemmedList) == 1:   #for some reason I have to do this to see if list is empty, I'm assuming when it's empty it returns a length of 1 since I'm initializing it as a list of lists??
            print "List not empty."
            for innerList in unStemmedList:
                if innerList[0] == word:
                    print "Adding 1 to [" + word + ", " + str(innerList[1]) + "]"
                    innerList[1] = (innerList[1] + 1)
                else:
                    print "Adding [" + word + ", 0]"
                    unStemmedList.append([word, 0])
        else:
            print "List empty."
            unStemmedList.append([word, 0])
            print unStemmedList[len(unStemmedList)-1]

return stemmedList
```

The final output ends up being:

List is empty.
["test1",0]
List not empty"

*Crash with list index out of range error* which points to the line `if innerList[0] == word`

Comment: why not use a `Counter`?  This is exactly what its for.

Comment: Your `else: print "List empty."` statement is inside the loop. Did you mean for that line to be called there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `a = [[]]`

Now, when you are appending to this list after encountering first word, you have

`a = [ [], ['test', 0] ]`

In the next iteration you are accessing the 0th element of an empty list which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `stemmedList` and `unStemmedList` are similar

```
stemmedList = [[]]
```

you have an empty list in your list of lists, it has no `[0]`.  Instead just initialize it to:

```
stemmedList = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this simpler?

```
counts = dict()
def plus1(key):
    if key in counts:
        counts[key] += 1
    else:
        counts[key] = 1

stoplist = "t1 t2 t1 t3 t1 t1 t2".split()
for word in stoplist:
    plus1(word)

counts
{'t2': 2, 't3': 1, 't1': 4}
```